# Change root node color in d3 Sankey graph based on additional column in data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, colors, sankey-diagram

I am referring this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/4xPx05PxnWxoQBhIj2lo?p=preview

[image]

The node colors here are dependent upon an additional column in data. The data is:

```
source,target,value,nodeColorTarget
DistA,Place1,1,blue
DistA,Place1,3,red
DistB,Place1,12,blue
DistB,Place2,2,grey
DistB,Place2,1,grey
DistB,Place3,2,blue
```

Now, I kind of need that I should be able to set some color to the node DistB. Currently, the color that is mentioned in the last occurrence of DistB is the color set to DistB. Can I not set some color to DistB without affecting it's target node, which here is Place3?
Thanks!

Comment: check the place where the rectangle is appended change the fill function to return the color as per your algorithm. `node.append("rect")
      .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy; })
      .attr("width", sankey.nodeWidth())
      .style("fill", function(d) {/*YOUR ALGO*/})` something like this http://plnkr.co/edit/S9rEgUsd2XMSRtXyxhMb?p=preview